# How to use the master detail flow theme with dynamic data?

Tags: java, android

By creating a new android project and selecting the master detail flow theme, this will provide with a sample on how to use this theme, which is good. My issue is that this example uses a static data and I need it to be dynamic. my application uses async task to get the data from a service in JSON format then I pars it and save it in the phone DB.

this is the DummyContent class:

```
public class DummyContent {

    /**
     * An array of sample (dummy) items.
     */
public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

/**
 * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
 */
public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

//  static {
//      // Add 3 sample items.
//      addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Item 1"));
//      addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Item 2"));
//      addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Item 3"));
//  }

public static void setContext(Context c) {
    if (db == null) db = new MyDbAdapter(c); // SQLiteOpenHelper + SQLiteDatabase manager
    if (db.isOpen() == false) {
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getProfiles(); // database query
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ProfileItem item = new ProfileItem(c.getString(0), c.getString(1),
                    c.getString(2));
                addItem(item);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}

private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

/**
 * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
 */
public static class DummyItem {
    public String id;
    public String content;

    public DummyItem(String id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

}

You can see that I commented the static data and added the "setContext" which should be called to add data from DB. My issue is that where and when should I call this function so that the data will show up? Should I call it in the "kind_name_ListFragment.java" "onCreate" or "kind_name_DetailFragment.java" "onCreate" or both (If both wont that be redundant) or somewhere else and is there a better solution?

Comment: no, I am still waiting for help :(

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that this example uses a static data and I need it to be
>   dynamic

Most straightforward way would be to call `DummyContent.setContext(Context)` before accessing `DummyContent.ITEMS`:

```
(kind_name_ListFragment.java)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Call to initialize DummyContent.ITEMS
    DummyContent.setContext(getActivity());

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(), 
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                                      android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));

}
```

You will need to call `DummyContent.setContext(getActivity())` whenever you need to initialize/update/refresh ITEMS and ITEM_MAP. Perhaps, placing a call to `ITEMS.clear()` and `ITEM_MAP.clear()` at the beginning of `setContext(Context)` would help when refreshing data.

> Should I call it in the "kind_name_ListFragment.java" "onCreate" or
>   "kind_name_DetailFragment.java" "onCreate" or both (If both wont that
>   be redundant) or somewhere else

Call it once as above in `kind_name_ListFragment.onCreate(Bundle)`, before `setListAdapter(...)`. No need to call it again in `kind_name_DetailFragment.onCreate(Bundle)`. When you need to update/refresh data:

```
DummyContent.setContext(getActivity());
((YourAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using the embedded database to store your data, Loader will be handy for you.

- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Update your SomethingListFragment and SomethingDetailFragment like the sample in this URL. You can dispose of the DummyContent class.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically use a CursorAdapter connecting to a ContentProvider which uses a database underneath in order to eliminate DummyContent.class, but that's a little more involved.

This should work:
1.) You probably mean to be using activity.getApplicationContext() for a Context when instantiating your MyDbAdapter. This will let your MyDbAdapter store the context instead you use to construct it. This will also let you invoke updates from an AsyncTask where you previously couldn't.
2.) Whenever your DummyContent.ITEMS list is updated you want to call notifyDataChange() on the ArrayListAdapter and it will take care of notifying the ListView to update its items.

Also, in case you don't like this answer: I think you missed closing your cursor "c".